# Control the material-ui slider with a play and stop buttons in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am using the continuous slider from metrial-ui in ReactJS project. I want to control the slider such that when click on the play button the slider start moving and stops when clicking stop.below  is the code of the slider.

```
   const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: 200,
  },
});
         
<div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography id="continuous-slider" gutterBottom>
        Volume
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item>
          <VolumeDown />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Slider value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-labelledby="continuous-slider" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <VolumeUp />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by calling `setState` to update the `Slider` value after an interval. You'll need to use `useEffect` to create and clean up the interval callback when the `isRunning` state changes:

```js
export default function ContinuousSlider() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(30);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
  const directionRef = useRef<"back" | "forward">("back");
  const intervalIdRef = useRef(0);

  const handleChange = (event: any, newValue: number | number[]) => {
    setValue(newValue as number);
  };
  const handleBack = () => {
    directionRef.current = "back";
    if (!isRunning) {
      setIsRunning(true);
    }
  };
  const handleNext = () => {
    directionRef.current = "forward";
    if (!isRunning) {
      setIsRunning(true);
    }
  };
  const handleStop = () => {
    setIsRunning((r) => !r);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isRunning) {
      intervalIdRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        if (directionRef.current === "forward") {
          setValue((v) => ++v);
        }
        if (directionRef.current === "back") {
          setValue((v) => --v);
        }
      }, 16);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current);
  }, [isRunning]);

  return (
    <>
      <IconButton onClick={handleStop}>
        <StopIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton onClick={handleBack}>
        <ArrowBackIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton onClick={handleNext}>
        <ArrowForwardIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Slider value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    </>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66983676/control-the-material-ui-slider-with-a-play-and-stop-buttons-in-react-js]